# Can't compile a VS2013 WinForms project after adding a dll reference

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a working VS2013 VB.NET 3.5 project. When I add and use a 3rd party DLL, the project stops compiling. However the DLL is working well in another .Net 4.0 Windows Forms project.

The error is

Warning               95           Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Stages.StagesGateway' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.               C:\Users\pvarma\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SAFELink\SAFELink MAS Dev\StagesFunctions.vb               1              9              SAFELink MAS Dev

The compile fails at Imports Stages.Stagegateway statement.

How can I fix the error please?

Comment: In the solution explorer have you checked whether there are there any problem indicators on the DLL item in References section in the project?

Comment: If the dll was designed for .net4.0 it probably won't work in .net3.5

Comment: Almost certainly the wrong version - .NET programmes cannot utilize a DLL that has a higher target Framework. I had this exact same issue on a recent project of my own.